# What is the term for when a word can not be translated directly?

Tags: terminology, translation

I was wondering if there's any term in linguistics when the word cannot be translated in just one/two words. I mean when it's really hard to explain the meaning, because there's no such thing in your language.

Comment: The process is called paraphrase or paraphrasing or explication; but I am not aware for a special word for the case when the translator has no choice but to resort to paraphrase.

Comment: The word for "an idea which can't be effectively translated into a different language [because it is specific to the culture of the source language]" is ***[realia](http://bit.ly/1KsWyng)***. The word for "a language lacking a word we'd otherwise expect it to have" is ***[lacuna](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/249150/55623)*** (aka *lexical gap*).

Comment: @user14237 Please make your question title as specific as possible, so people will know immediately what your question is about prior to reading the full body - this way, you are more likely to attract answers. "Question about translation" is too unspecific. For more information, read the guidelines in the [Help Center](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).